# selecting rows either side of a record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to select 4 rows either side of a record from an images table that I have.

So far I have the following: -

```
with myresults as(
    select mykey, imageThumb,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY mykey)AS Row from images where userid = @userID
)

select * from myresults where 

row < ((select row from myresults where mykey=@imageID)+5)
and
row > ((select row from myresults where mykey=@imageID)-5)
```

This does work okay but I was wondering if there's a better/simpler way of doing it

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using self join u can easily achieve the target. Try this

```
WITH myresults
     AS (SELECT Row_number()
                  OVER (
                    ORDER BY mykey)AS Rn,
                mykey,
                imageThumb
         FROM   images where userid = @userID)
SELECT *
FROM   myresults a
       JOIN myresults b
         ON a.rn BETWEEN b.Rn - 5 AND b.rn + 5
WHERE  a.mykey = @imageID
```

**Example**

```
CREATE TABLE #images
  (
     mykey      INT,
     imageThumb VARCHAR(50)
  );

WITH cte
     AS (SELECT 1       AS id,
                Newid() AS d
         UNION ALL
         SELECT id + 1,
                Newid() d
         FROM   cte
         WHERE  id < 10)
INSERT INTO #images
SELECT *
FROM   cte;

WITH myresults
     AS (SELECT Row_number()
                  OVER (
                    ORDER BY mykey)AS Rn,
                mykey,
                imageThumb
         FROM   #images)
SELECT *
FROM   myresults a
       JOIN myresults b
         ON a.rn BETWEEN b.Rn - 3 AND b.rn + 3
WHERE  a.mykey = 4
```

Answer (score 4):

You are on the right track, but you need to do the `row_number()` first and then the `where`.  Here is one method using a `cross join`:

```
with myresults as(
    select mykey, imageThumb, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY mykey) as Row
    from images
)  
select m.*
from myresults m cross join
     (select * from myresults where userid = @userID) u
where m.row < u.row + 5 and m.row > u.r - 5;
```